# Sitecore: loginPage?

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to set a loginPage value on a Sitecore site in the web.config. The file referenced in the loginPage is an Sitecore item, so it is not a psycical page on the server. No matter how i reference to it, it doesnot work. I get one of 2 errors (depending on how i refrecen to the file);

The resource cannot be found.
Error executing child request for /sitecore/login. (The path beeing the one i referenced in the web.config)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you request the item directly in your browser without being logged in? The item path of the loginPage attribute has to be relative to the startPath of your site. I assume /sitecore/login is not relative to your site root?

Comment: I have just written a blog post about this which should get published tomorrow so i will post a link Are you in a single site solution?
Your Sites Node config what is the root path?
If the Root Path = /Home
Then the Login = /Login So path would be /Content/Home/Login in the tree. Are you able to view the page in the editor? Or experience editor (Sitecore 8) If so have you published the Page and the template? Have you tried rendering a link pointing to the login page? Does that work? Hope that helps :) Charlie

Answer (score 18):

The explanatory comment in web.config says that 'loginPage' attribute should be `The path to the login page to use. Must point to a physical file or a page in a site that does NOT require login.` 'Require login' means denied Read permissions for the Anonymous user. This Anonymous user is the one in the domain specified for this site.

For instance, if you want to have login page set for the '**website**' site, you should make sure that **extranet\Anonymous** has read permission to the item you specified.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

The loginPage attribute is actually a URL, not an item path. Include the full path with extension -- e.g. /MyAccount/Login.aspx

Comment: Tried that too - without luck though :-(

Comment: What's the error you get using that? I assume you can access the page directly using that URL?

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting the url in the browser to your login page.  If you cannot reach the page itself or if it throws an error in the browser then accessing it in the web.config will not work.

Once you have the login page coming up in the url in the browser using the path  yoursite/login or whatever sitecore tree path you have set up.  Then add it to the web.config.

Also, in the content tree you can click on security and access viewer for the login item. Then select the anonymous role. If its is a security issue then you will see which role is affecting the security settings for anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Type this in browser"Url of ur website/Sitecore/showconfig.aspx" .. Here you will get a combination of all the .config files being used. Also, you can just check in fiddler(a software) to see what else you get in response apart from resource can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if you could also paste the settings you applied in the web.config, but this is how I understand the question.

You wanted to create a client user login page, not overriding the Sitecore login page.

If so, you have to ensure that it's under the home item (*sitecore> content >home > YOUR_LOGIN_PAGE*).

If outside the home item, eg. *sitecore> content >YOUR_WEBSITE > YOUR_LOGIN_PAGE* then you have to configure that in the *sitedefinition.config* because that is somehow treated as a new site and not part of the freshly installed Sitecore.

To validate that you have applied it correctly, try accessing the showconfig page on your browser (*eg. http://YOUR_WEBSITE/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx*)

Additional stuffs you might want to double check:

- Make sure you were able to publish it on the web database, if not try accessing in the preview mode
- Make sure that the item has layout and rendering definition. Otherwise, it won't work.
- Make sure you have the right permission, for you to be able to access the page. I would assume you're in the admin role

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by modified setting :

`<setting name="RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect" value="false" />"`

which is false by default.

According to notes in config file If true, Sitecore will use `Server.Transfer` instead of `Response.Redirect`. But `Server.Transfer` is not good option for regular login page redirect because:

ASP.NET does not verify that the current user is authorized to view the resource delivered by the Transfer method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in Sitecore.config file

```
<site name="shell" ... loginPage="yoururl" ... />
<site name="login" ... virtualFolder="/yoururl" ... />
<site name="admin" ... virtualFolder="/yoururl" ... loginPage="/yoururl/login.aspx" />
```